# "Process exited with code 2" at Step 2: Execute webpack of Team City deployment

Tags: webpack, teamcity

We are seeing an error when our automated Team City deploy executes, specifically something to do with Webpack. The output that is printed:

```
[19:12:56]
(node:5308) DeprecationWarning: loaderUtils.parseQuery() received a non-string value which can be problematic, see https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/issues/56
[19:12:56]
parseQuery() will be replaced with getOptions() in the next major version of loader-utils.
[19:12:58]
ts-loader: Using typescript@2.9.2 and C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80d0099932f101d3\tsconfig.json
[19:13:38]
Process exited with code 2
```

We were able to determine that the deprecation warning is not related, and we can make that warning not appear at all, however it doesn't affect the end result; we still get an error with code 2. This issue started happening about 4 months ago and we're not really sure why. When I run the webpack development build locally, I also get "Process terminated with code 2", but my co-worker does not. We compared our `webpack.config.js` and `package.json` and they are the same. We aren't really sure what to check at this point.

Any thoughts on why this could be occurring and what to check? Below is our package.json. **UPDATE**: Webpack.config.js is included below it.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Redacted",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Redacted Website",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^1.5.2",
    "backbone": "^1.3.3",
    "backbone.marionette": "^3.0.0",
    "backbone.radio": "^2.0.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.4.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-validator": "^0.11.9",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "glob": "^7.0.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-debug": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-exec": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-foreach": "^0.1.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-msbuild": "0.4.4",
    "gulp-newer": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-rimraf": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.5",
    "jquery": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery-datepicker": "1.11.4",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "nunjucks": "^3.0.0",
    "nunjucks-loader": "^2.4.5",
    "rimraf": "^2.4.3",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.4",
    "saas": "^1.0.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "vinyl": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack-strip": "^0.1.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.16",
    "xmlpoke": "^0.1.12",
    "yargs": "^6.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/backbone": "^1.3.33",
    "@types/backbone.marionette": "0.0.20",
    "@types/backbone.radio": "^0.8.32",
    "@types/bluebird": "^3.0.35",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.32",
    "@types/chai": "^4.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/karma": "^1.7.1",
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.44",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.49",
    "@types/nunjucks": "0.0.32",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.7.33",
    "bourbon": "^4.2.7",
    "breakpoint-sass": "^2.7.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gulp-nuget-restore": "^0.4.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.5.3",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.5",
    "mocha": "^4.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "0.0.93",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/karma start",
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch",
    "build": "WEBPACK_ENV=production ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js --port 9000 --host 0.0.0.0 --content-base dev/ --hot --inline --progress --colors"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+{our git url redacted}"
  },
  "author": "Redacted",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**Webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker");
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');


/**
 * Webpack Docs:
 * - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/
 * - https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/ (1.x -> 2.x)
 */


var publicPath = '/static/';

var config = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname),
    entry: {
        // necessary to copy image files to /static, see README.md
        "imgs":                                 "./src/Project/Redacted.Website/code/@static/@imgs/index.js",
        "js/common":                            "common/index.js",
        "css/common":                           "common/index.scss",
        "js/ui-kit":                            "ui-kit/index.js",
        "css/ui-kit":                           "ui-kit/index.scss",
        "js/home":                              "home/index.js",
        "css/home":                             "home/index.scss",
        "js/landing-hero-slider":               "landing-hero-slider/index.js",
        "js/nav-pinned":                        "nav-pinned/index.js",
        "js/curriculum-wheel":                  "curriculum-wheel/index.js",
        "js/meet-us-form":                      "meet-us-form/index.js",
        "js/action-slider":                     "action-slider/index.js",
        "js/meet-teachers-module-slider":       "meet-teachers-module-slider/index.js",
        "js/testimonials-slider":               "testimonials-slider/index.js",
        "js/events-module-slider":              "events-module-slider/index.js",
        "js/curriculum-module-slider":          "curriculum-module-slider/index.js",
        "js/awards-module-slider":              "awards-module-slider/index.js",
        "js/sample-lunch-module-slider":        "sample-lunch-module-slider/index.js",
        "js/faq":                               "faq/index.js",
        "js/about-welcome-slider":              "about-welcome-slider/index.js",
        "js/see-more":                          "see-more/index.js",
        "js/curriculum-wheel-tabbed":           "curriculum-wheel-tabbed/index.js",
        "js/curriculum-tabbed-slider":          "curriculum-tabbed-slider/index.js",
        "js/curriculum-tabbed-mobile-select":   "curriculum-tabbed-mobile-select/index.js",
        "js/curriculum-tabbed-text-scroller":   "curriculum-tabbed-text-scroller/index.js",
        "js/lead-form-module":                  "lead-form-module/index.js",
        "js/lead-form-in-page":                 "lead-form-in-page/index.js",
        "js/lead-form-progressive-disclosure":  "lead-form-progressive-disclosure/index.js",
        "js/passcode-modal":                    "passcode-modal/index.js",
    },
    output: {
        path:          path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/Project/Redacted.Website/code/static"),
        filename:      "[name].js",
        publicPath:    publicPath,
        chunkFilename: "[id].chunck.[ext]"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
          name:     "js/common",
          filename: "js/common.js"
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: "[name].css"}),
        new BundleTracker({filename: "../../webpack-stats.json"}),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            "fetch":   "imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch",
            "Promise": "bluebird",
            "$":       "jquery",    // bootstrap.js support
            "jQuery":  "jquery",    // bootstrap.js support
        }),
        // SEE: https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            // { "from": "@copy/path/to/file.ext", "to": "path/to/file.ext"},
        ]),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: "css-loader"
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    use: [{
                        loader: "css-loader", options: { minimize: true } 
                    }, {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            data: "$staticUrl: '" + publicPath + "';"
                        }
                    }]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "ts-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|svg)(\?\S*)?$/,
                exclude: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "@imgs")
                ],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: "fonts/[name].[ext]",
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|gif|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
                exclude: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")
                ],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: "imgs/[name].[ext]",
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(njk|nunjucks)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "nunjucks-loader",
                    options: {
                        config: path.resolve(__dirname, "nunjucks.config.js")
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".webpack.js", "web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
        alias: {
            "webworkify":        "webworkify-webpack",
            "bootstrap":         "bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap",
            "bootstrap-styles":  "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets",
            "breakpoint-styles": "breakpoint-sass/stylesheets",
            "bourbon-styles":    "bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets",
        },
        modules: ["node_modules", "./src/Project/Redacted.Website/code/@static/@modules", "./src/Project/Redacted.Website/code/@static/@css", "./src/Project/Redacted.Website/code/@static/@imgs", "./src/Project/Redacted.Website/code/@static/@tests"]
    }

}

//if (process.env.WEBPACK_ENV == 'production'){
    config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            screw_ie8: true,
            warnings: false,
            unsafe_comps: true,
            unsafe: true,
            pure_getters: true
        },
        comments: false,
        sourceMap: true
        })
    ])

    config.module.rules = config.module.rules.concat([
        {
            test: /\.(js|ts)$/,
            loader: "webpack-strip?strip[]=console.warn,strip[]=console.log"
        },
    ])
//}

module.exports = config
```

Comment: Do you use package-lock.json? Ensure you have the same versions of dependencies in node_moduels

Comment: @klimat We do have a `package-lock.json`, and it is 7000 lines long. Is there no way to regenerate node_modules or the lock.json file so that we know they are the same? I assume I would have to compare the lock.json against every package.json in every module folder underneath node_modules, which would take forever.

Comment: Ensure just by removing `node_modules` and let `npm install` against the same `package-lock.json` on TeamCity and your local machine. It's also nice to upgrade your npm to the latest version and use the same across machines. `npm install -g npm`. It's 6.8.0 now.